# Can I create a collection using MongoClient().getDatabase("dbName"); , with analitical storage enabled? (C#)

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

In order to create a mongoDb collection in Azure CosmosDB Im using MongoClient().getDatabase("dbName");
and then performing insert operations so my db/collection is created at the end.

However, the requirement is also that the created collection will have analytical storage enabled.
My implementation is written in C#

My question is then, how can I create using the MongoClient a collection which will have the Analytical Store option set to true?

Thanks in advance

1. I know that this option(enable analitical storage) can be set when using DataExplorer at Azure
   Portal
2. I gave a try and used CreateCollection method with CreateCollectionOptions for MongoDb but dit not
   found anything there for the storage enabling

Answer (score 0):

To create a MongoDB collection with analytical storage enabled in Azure Cosmos DB using the C# driver, you can set the analytical store property when creating the collection. Here's an example code snippet:

```
    using MongoDB.Driver;
    using MongoDB.Bson;
    using Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.MongoDB.BulkExecutor;
    using Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.MongoDB.BulkExecutor.BulkImport;

    string connectionString = "your_connection_string_here";
    string databaseName = "your_database_name_here";
    string collectionName = "your_collection_name_here";

    MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(new MongoUrl(connectionString));
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient(settings);

    IMongoDatabase database = client.GetDatabase(databaseName);

    BsonDocument collectionOptions = new BsonDocument
    {
        { "analyticalStoreEnabled", true }
    };

    database.CreateCollection(collectionName, new CreateCollectionOptions
    {
        StorageEngine = new BsonDocument
        {
            { "wiredTiger", new BsonDocument
                {
                    { "configString", "block_compressor=zstd" }
                }
            }
        },
        Validator = new BsonDocument("$jsonSchema", new BsonDocument
        {
            { "bsonType", "object" }
        }),
        AutoIndexId = true,
        MaxSize = null,
        Capped = false,
        Collation = null,
        AnalyticalStoreOptions = collectionOptions
    });
```